# Asynchronously calling an external REST API from controller or view?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, async-await, steam-web-api

I've been trying  to wrap my head around this for too long. This is my first time with C# and .NET and apart from dabbling with C++ almost 15 years ago I have no programming experience. REST APIs and asynchronicity are new concepts to me.

I'm trying to make a scoreboard page in .NET MVC 5 consisting of a simple table with rows containing values retrieved from a MySQL database.
Each row in the database table represents a unique player along with his various stat values. I've created a model to represent each player, `PlayerRow`, and am passing a `List<PlayerRow>` to my view where the table gets generated via `@foreach (PlayerRow playerrow in Model)`.

This is my current `ActionResult PlayerList()`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PlayerList()
    {
        List<PlayerRow> PlayerRows = new List<PlayerRow>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySQLConnStr"];
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM `rankme`";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        PlayerRows.Add(new PlayerRow
                        {
                            TableID = rdr["id"].ToString(),
                            LegacySteamID = rdr["steam"].ToString(),
                            Steam64 = ConvertToSteam64(rdr["steam"].ToString()),
                            Name = rdr["name"].ToString(),
                            IP = rdr["lastip"].ToString(),
                            Score = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["score"]),
                            etc etc...
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return View(PlayerRows);
    }
}
```

Relevant content from my `PlayerList.cshtml`:

```
        @foreach (PlayerRow playerrow in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="avatar" id="@playerrow.Steam64"><img src="~/Content/placeholder.png"</th>
            <td><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/@playerrow.Steam64">@playerrow.Name</a></td>
            <td>@playerrow.Score</td>
            <td>@playerrow.Kills</td>
            <td>@playerrow.Deaths</td>
            <td>@playerrow.Assists</td>
            etc etc...
        </tr>
    }
```

The MySQL connection works just fine and the table gets displayed just how I want it to. (albeit not quite polished, yet)
[Picture of my current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwqHB.png)

What I would like to do next is replace the placeholder avatar in each table row with the players avatar retreived via the Steam API. Each players avatar url can be retreived from the Steam API by calling `https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key=_API_KEY_&steamids=_STEAMID64_` which returns a json response:

```
{
"response":{
  "players":[
     {
        "steamid":"EXAMPLE_STEAMID",
        "communityvisibilitystate":3,
        "profilestate":1,
        "personaname":"EXAMPLE_NAME",
        "commentpermission":1,
        "profileurl":"EXAMPLE_STEAM_PROFILE_URL",
        "avatar":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/EXAMPLE_AVATAR.jpg",
        "avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/81/EXAMPLE_AVATAR_medium.jpg",
        "avatarfull":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/EXAMPLE_AVATAR_full.jpg",
        "lastlogoff":1586222967,
        "personastate":0,
        "realname":"EXAMPLE_REALNAME",
        "primaryclanid":"103582",
        "timecreated":1070200624,
        "personastateflags":0,
        "loccountrycode":"US"
     }
  ]
```

So I guess that requires me to make the request using `HttpClient()` and awaiting the response. That's where I get lost because I can't seem to await the response outside of an async method. Maybe using AJAX (which I've never used) would be more appropriate?

Could I create an async method to consume the Steam API? When and from where should that method be called?

Answer (score 1):

To call an async method from a controller you can simply change your signature to

`public async Task<IActionResult> PlayerList(CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

From here, you'll be able to call any `async` method you like.

I don't really know the Steam API so if you're going to be making lots of network calls it might be better to do this on the Browser/Javascript side (lazy-loading the avatars as the browser scrolls into view).